# GROUP BY problem with varchar

Tags: t-sql

There are links stored in a DB as varchars. With these links I want to use GROUP BY.

```
http://example.com
http://example.com
http://example.com
```

SQL over that data:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c, Url
    FROM Advertisements
    GROUP BY Url
```

I want this output:

```
c Url 
3 http://example.com
```

But instead I get this three times:

```
c Url 
1 http://example.com
```

Why doesn't SELECT group the varchar fields? They are the same but GROUP BY does not detect that. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste the actual **data** into your question?

Comment: lol.. the links aren't terribly useful

Comment: I'd like to help, but none of this makes any sense to me.  Pls update with what your data is in the table, the query you're using, and what you want as the final result.

Comment: no this links are not for click. This are links stored in DB i use for group by.

Comment: No need for actual URLs.

Comment: @Will foo.com actually does go somewhere though; example.com is reserved for things like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The endings are different

**7**​i18704

**5**​i18704

**4**​i18704

Following your comment I have updated and they GROUP as expected. What do you get when you try this?

```
CREATE TABLE #Advertisements
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
Url VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO #Advertisements VALUES
('http://example.com')

INSERT INTO #Advertisements VALUES
('http://example.com')

INSERT INTO #Advertisements VALUES
('http://example.com')



SELECT COUNT(*) c, Url
    FROM #Advertisements
    GROUP BY Url
```

Answer (score 3):

If the string containing those URLS is the data that is stored, they are not the same url, each one is differnent therfore group by would put each ina differnt group.

Answer (score 1):

Just like HLGEM and Martin said, the whole text in the field has to be the same so that the GROUP BY works, you can use something like GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Url, 0, 30), this way you'll get:

URL | COUNT

`http://example.com | 3`