# GROUP BY clause sees all VARCHAR fields as different

Tags: t-sql, group-by, varchar

I have witnessed a strange behaviour while trying to **GROUP BY** a **VARCHAR** field.

Let the following example, where I try to spot customers that have changed name at least once in the past.

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomersHistory
(
Id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
CustomerId INT,
Name VARCHAR(200)
)

INSERT INTO #CustomersHistory VALUES (12, 'AAA')
INSERT INTO #CustomersHistory VALUES (12, 'AAA')
INSERT INTO #CustomersHistory VALUES (12, 'BBB')
INSERT INTO #CustomersHistory VALUES (44, '444')

SELECT ch.CustomerId, count(ch.Name) AS cnt
  FROM #CustomersHistory ch
  GROUP BY ch.CustomerId  HAVING  count(ch.Name) != 1
```

Which oddly yields (as if 'AAA' from first INSERT was different from the second one)

```
CustomerId  cnt  //  (I was expecting)
12          3    //   2
44          1    //   1
```

- Is this behaviour specific to T-SQL?
- Why does it behave in this rather counter-intuitive way?
- How is it customary to overcome this limitation?

**Note:** This question is very similar to [GROUP BY problem with varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311251/group-by-problem-with-varchar), where I didn't find the answer to Why

**Side Note:** Is it good practice to use `HAVING  count(ch.Name) != 1` instead of `HAVING  count(ch.Name) > 1` ?

Comment: To comment on the > 1 vs != 1, in many cases (though not necessarily yours) it's possible for count() to be 0 (nulls are ignored, for example.) but 0 != 1 and thus a possibility of some unexpected behavior. It's just a habit of mine.

Comment: I will do my own research on this side note, and possibly ask a new question. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `COUNT()` operator will count all rows regardless of value. I think you might want to use a `COUNT(DISTINCT ch.Name)` which will only count unique names.

```
SELECT ch.CustomerId, count(DISTINCT ch.Name) AS cnt
  FROM #CustomersHistory ch
  GROUP BY ch.CustomerId  HAVING  count(DISTINCT ch.Name) > 1
```

For more information, take a look at the [COUNT()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) article on book online